# NoClassDefFoundError for class within app package

Tags: java, android, noclassdeffounderror

**Below is my activity :**
**com.domain.app.SampleActivity.java**

```
public class SampleActivity extends Activity {

  @Override
    protected void onCreate(final Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        setContentView(R.layout.sample_layout);

        DataProviderClass dataProvider = new DataProviderClass();
    }
}
```

**com.domain.app.anotherFolder.DataProviderClass.java**

```
public class DataProviderClass {
  private DataProviderClassHelper helper = new DataProviderClassHelper();
}
```

**com.domain.app.anotherFolder.DataProviderClassHelper.java**

```
public class DataProviderClassHelper implements ExternalLibInterface {
  public DataProviderClassHelper() {
    }
}
```

**Below are the logs :**

> I/art     (22555): Rejecting re-init on previously-failed class java.lang.Class
>   I/art     (22555): Rejecting re-init on previously-failed class java.lang.Class
>   I/art     (22555): Rejecting re-init on previously-failed class java.lang.Class
>   I/art     (22555): Rejecting re-init on previously-failed class java.lang.Class
>   I/art     (22555): Rejecting re-init on previously-failed class java.lang.Class
>   E/AndroidRuntime(22555): Process: com.domain.app, PID: 22555
>   E/AndroidRuntime(22555): java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com.domain.app.anotherFolder.DataProviderClassHelper.java
>   E/AndroidRuntime(22555):    at com.domain.app.anotherFolder.DataProviderClass.java.(DataProviderClass.java:77)
>   E/AndroidRuntime(22555):    at com.domain.app.SampleActivity..onCreate(SampleActivity.java:64)
>   W/ActivityManager( 1103):   Force finishing activity 1 com.domain.app/.SampleActivity

It doesn't make sense to me one class is initialized but another class in the same folder is giving me an error. 
In other similar questions people were facing this error in external libraries they were trying to import and that didn't really help me.

Comment: is `multidex` enabled in the project?

Comment: This usually happens when something is found at compile time but not at runtime. Can you try to delete cache and rebuild your project again and also restart it.

Comment: I resolved this issue and what you said is accurate. In my `DataProviderClassHelper` I was actually implementing an interface that was provided in a stub jar of an external library. Since it was `provided`, the code would compile successfully but that actual thing was not available to me at runtime. To be able to access the actual thing on the system I had to add some library specific component in my `AndroidManifest.xml`. So the solution might not exactly help everyone but it will help people identify the cause of the issue.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In my `DataProviderClassHelper` I was actually implementing `ExternalLibInterface` interface that was provided in a stub jar of an external library.
 Since it was `provided`, the code would compile successfully but that actual thing was not available to me at runtime. To be able to access the actual thing on the system I had to add some library specific component in my `AndroidManifest.xml`. So the solution might not exactly help everyone but it will help people identify the cause of the issue.
In my case it was due to unavailability of `ExternalLibInterface` at runtime.